# JavaScript problem making redirect and posting prompt data to URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am looking to take the data submitted from a popup message and pass it via post to a URL and then redirect the user to a new URL.

If fname and email are there I would like to post fname and email to a URL.

How can I do this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.msgbox("<p><b>Grocery Coupons Newsletter</b></p><p>Save $$$ With Coupons and Samples in your E-Mail</p>", {
    type    : "prompt",
    inputs  : [
      {type: "text",     label: "Insert your First Name:", value: "", required: true},
      {type: "text", label: "Insert your Email:", required: true}
    ],
    buttons : [
      {type: "submit", value: "OK"},
      {type: "cancel", value: "Exit"}
    ]
  }, function(fname, email) {
    if (fname) {
      
      window.location = "http://www.google.com/";
    }
  });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need a form (write HTML or create one through the DOM), attach the data to that form and `submit()` it.

Answer (score 0):

You could also:

1. Serialize your form parameters into the redirect URL location
2. Send the users to that URL
3. Parse that GET information serverside
4. Redirect the user via the Location: header to the final destination.

By doing this you don't need to dynamically create a new form in the DOM to submit through.